# i need help to solve select query where IN clause?

Tags: php, arrays, session, select

i need help to solve select query where IN clause?

1) now problem is that select query not working `where pid IN ($pid)`? 
2) second problem is that `CCID input text` is empty?

when i `echo $pid=implode ($new_product).'<br>';` this `PID` are showing which are created as $_SESSION['pid']..!

**Error When I Used ($pid)**

```
CCID Problem
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1
```

**Page Where Session Pid Created**

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['pid1'][]=$_POST['pid'];


function get_id($id){
$result1=mysql_query("select * from products where id='$id'")
or die("Id Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
$results1= array();
$k=0; // add the new line
while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){
$results1[$k] =$row1['id'];
$k++;
}
return $results1;
}

$pid1=get_id($id);

<form method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="pid[]" value="<?php echo $pid1?>" />
</form>
```

**Page2.Php**

```
session_start();
if(is_array($_SESSION['pid1'])){
$max=count($_SESSION['pid1']);  
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++){
$new_product=$_SESSION['pid1'][$i];
echo $pid=implode ($new_product).'<br>';
}}

$result=mysql_query("SELECT id AS ccid FROM cart where pid IN ($pid) ") 
or die("CCID Problem"."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<input type="text" name="ccid[]" value="<?php echo $row['ccid'];?>" />

<?php }?>
```

Comment: Echo out the SELECT statement with your IN clause in it. Does it work when you run it in the database? What does the error from mysql_error say?

Comment: @andrewsi nothing showing `ccid`  in the `input type text name ccid`?

Comment: That's because your query is failing. Echo out the query you're generating. Run it in the database.

Comment: @andrewsi i have already try query in the database and got results?? which i want example
`select id as ccid from cart where pid in (20,22)` and it is working in the database but what is problem with `$pid`?

Comment: Your for loop on page2.php looks weird anyway. You overwrite `$new_product` at every iteration. Is that on purpose ?

Comment: Could you add the query you've generated from your code to the question, in that case?

Comment: **Error When I Used ($pid)**

    CCID Problem
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
    to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: It doesn't look like `$id` has been initialised where you call `get_id($id)` in the first PHP file, not sure whether that could be part of your problem, but it might be worth checking where `$id` was meant to be set

Answer (score 3):

1. use   `echo $pid=implode (",",$new_product).'<br>';`
2. `CCID input text` is empty because of the issue above.

Suppose you have pids which is `array(1, 2 3)` in session. What is happening is:

You use:

```
$pid = implode($new_product);
```

This will create string by concatenating the array values WITHOUT any separators. So you get:

`$pid = 123`

What you need is a comma in between them. So you have to use:

```
$pid=implode (",",$new_product);
```

Here the first argument is the comma, which is used as the glue to hold the array values in the string so the result becomes:

`$pid=1,2,3`;

And it is this string that you need to use in your query with the `IN` clause.

Also move the line which gets the pid `$pid=implode (",",$new_product);` **outside** the `for` loop;

Comment: It might bear clarifying that `implode` without a glue parameter defaults to an empty string.

Comment: @andrewsi: I guess when he sees the difference between the answer and he code he posted, he will work that out for himself :-)

Comment: @Raidenace - We can but hope.

Comment: @andrewsi i think problem is here `SELECT id AS ccid FROM cart where pid IN ($pid)` in the `$pid` what do you say?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi - the first issue is that you're not calling implode correctly. The second is that you're generating `$pid` inside the for loop, so if it runs more than once, you're only getting the last set of data.

Comment: @FarhanDharsi: I think both andrewsi and Jim H were true about adding some more explanations. Please check the update to my answer.

Comment: @Raidenace you said `Also move the line which gets the pid $pid=implode (",",$new_product); outside the for loop`

but i have already move outside of looop `$pid` but showing only one and single `pid`?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi: in page2.php the line is still inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_product = array();
for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++){
   $new_product[]=$_SESSION['pid1'][$i];
}
$pid=implode (', ', $new_product);
```